# Read text file with different line length in R

Tags: r

I have a text file with more than 60,000 lines that I need to read. I have used the fread function and my code is below. (sample two lines shown below). I need an output as shown in the "Output" table.

Can somebody help me to get the output I want. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(data.table)
file1 <- 'sample.txt'
data <- fread(file1)

Error:

Error in fread(in_file1) : 
  Expecting 13 cols, but line 20 contains text after processing all cols. Try again with fill=TRUE. Another reason could be that fread's logic in distinguishing one or more fields having embedded sep=' ' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes has failed. If quote='' doesn't help, please file an issue to figure out if the logic could be improved.


1999~24~0000049~079~0119~0780~0011~90~0030~9970~                    ~A~ .6500~     3.3000~           ~          ~            ~            ~            ~            ~         ~1.000~  2029 ~00000000~PL~01~210~L001~061~N~023~W~035
1999~24~0000049~079~0100~0860~0041~44~0030~0160~    BUEUPT          ~A~ .7000~     2.4000~     1.9600~    279.90~      7,503 ~      4,059 ~     44,237 ~     70,536 ~    150.0~1.000~   629 ~05111999~PL~01~220~L001~061~N~022~W~020~L002~061~N~022~W~021~L003~061~N~022~W~029~L004~060~N~022~W~016~L005~060~N~022~W~021
```

Output:

```
    1999~24~0000049~079~0119~0780~0011~90~0030~9970~                    ~A~ .6500~     3.3000~           ~          ~            ~            ~            ~            ~         ~1.000~  2029 ~00000000~PL~01~210~L001~061~N~023~W~035
    1999~24~0000049~079~0100~0860~0041~44~0030~0160~    BUEUPT          ~A~ .7000~     2.4000~     1.9600~    279.90~      7,503 ~      4,059 ~     44,237 ~     70,536 ~    150.0~1.000~   629 ~05111999~PL~01~220~L002~061~N~022~W~021
    1999~24~0000049~079~0100~0860~0041~44~0030~0160~    BUEUPT          ~A~ .7000~     2.4000~     1.9600~    279.90~      7,503 ~      4,059 ~     44,237 ~     70,536 ~    150.0~1.000~   629 ~05111999~PL~01~220~L003~061~N~022~W~029
    1999~24~0000049~079~0100~0860~0041~44~0030~0160~    BUEUPT          ~A~ .7000~     2.4000~     1.9600~    279.90~      7,503 ~      4,059 ~     44,237 ~     70,536 ~    150.0~1.000~   629 ~05111999~PL~01~220~L004~060~N~022~W~016
    1999~24~0000049~079~0100~0860~0041~44~0030~0160~    BUEUPT          ~A~ .7000~     2.4000~     1.9600~    279.90~      7,503 ~      4,059 ~     44,237 ~     70,536 ~    150.0~1.000~   629 ~05111999~PL~01~220~L005~060~N~022~W~021
```

Comment: What kind of data format is that? Looks very strange and I doubt that `fread` will work with this one.

Comment: Your data format is not right. `~` this may be causing an issue. From error what I can see is that for some line there are columns missing while using `fread`. You could use `fill = TRUE`. `fread("sample.txt", fill = TRUE)`

Comment: You specify that you are using a **text** (.txt) file. According to the documentation: _"`fread` is for regular delimited files; i.e., where every row has the same number of columns."_ Therefore you should convert your file to be a delimited file, and then also reassure that each row has the same number of columns.

Comment: Does that data in the text file actually contain white space like shown in the example? Or is it stored without white space like this: "1999~24~0000049~079~0100~0860~0041~44~0030~0160~BUEUPT~A~.7000~2.4000~1.9600~279.90~7,503~4,059~44,237~70,536~150.0~1.000~629~05111999~PL~01~220~L001~061~N~022~W~020~L002~061~N~022~W~021~L003~061~N~022~W~029~L004~060~N~022~W~016~L005~060~N~022~W~021"

Comment: Yes it does. It has the white spaces.

Comment: Additional lengths to lines happens after column 33. If can check for ~ after 33 column and repeat the remaining line by breaking ~ would be helpful.